# Wordpress scripts not found

Tags: wordpress

hello everyone i used functions to enable my scripts but its does not work, but styles working well. help with scripts

[image: my err]

[image: my html]

[image: my structure]

[image: my functions php]

Comment: Please put your code in your post.  With that said, you don't actually enqueue the stylesheet.

Comment: @HowardE i dont undertand.. please give me example

Comment: You can't do like this in enqueue the stylesheet. http://prntscr.com/utg4ly

Comment: added like this wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

Comment: First... please paste your code into your post.  Do not attach your code as a screenshot.